# How to add Image upload suppoer in NodeJS using multer?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multer

I'm creating a food delivery application and for the backend I'm using NodeJS. In this app a vendor can register themselves and can add dishes and also can upload picture of the dish.
But I'm not able to come up with the logic that how can I make a vendor to upload picture of the dish simultaneously when he is adding a dish to the menu.

vendorModel.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const vendorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    vendorName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },

    contactNumber: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

    vendorAddress: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    eta: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

    dishes: [
        {
            dishName: {
                type: String,
            },

            dishType: {
                type: String,
            },

            cuisineType: {
                type: String,
            },

            price: {
                type: Number,
            },

            picOfDish: {
                type: Buffer
            }

        }
    ],

    tokens: [
        {
            token: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            }
        }
    ],

    outletPicture: {
        type: Buffer
    }

});
```

Here I've created a route to add dish but I'm not able to add picture of each dish when a vendor creates a dish.
Please help me to create the logic.
vendorRoutes.js

```js
const upload = multer({
    limits: {

        fileSize: 1000000

    },
    fileFilter(req, file, cb) {

        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/))
            return cb(new Error('Please upload an image'))

        cb(undefined, true)
    }
});

router.post('/vendor/addDish', auth, async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const vendor = await Vendor.findById(req.body.id);
        if (!vendor) throw new Error('No Vendor Found');
        const dish = await vendor.addDishes(req.body);
        res.send(dish);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(400).send();
    }
});
```

Comment: How about uploading first the image get a URL and use that one when you are adding the dish.

Comment: Like uploading an image in Google Drive and Copy paste that link at the time of dish creation.?

Comment: More like creating a dedicated route for uploading images like `/upload` which will get an image blob save it somewhere and then return a URL. Afterwards you could use that URL when you want to reference that image.

Comment: I can create route but how can i generate URL for the same?

Comment: You already use multer so I guess the upload part is done. What you need now is to serve the folder which contains the images. This is a common task and I am sure you can find a tutorial on the subject or even multer's documentation could help.

Comment: @oyeshubhu Checkout this tutorial https://stackabuse.com/handling-file-uploads-in-node-js-with-expres-and-multer/